# How to create a better explode effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I've an animation I'm trying to complete that should resemble a bubble that come up from below and then, on click, explode showing a text.

The current effect is made by this bit of code:

```
jQuery('.bubble1').on('click', function () {
 jQuery(this).stop(true,true).hide('explode', { pieces: 75 } , 1000, function() {
  jQuery('.corpo-del-testo').show();
 });
});
```

[I've also made a jsFiddle to demonstrate the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Soraph/UaLDj/6/).

I would like to have a better burst effect but I can't find a solution for it, anyone had a similar problem or know how to achieve a bubble like explosion that is more "realistic"? Like a burst.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific what "better" means.

Comment: @Juhana Something less "pixellated"

Comment: Refer this Jquery game http://motyar.blogspot.in/2010/04/angel-dreams-jquery-game.html

Comment: if you are decent with **jQuery** you may be able to play with the explode source code and tweak some things. [it is here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js)

Comment: Thanks you both, I'll read the suggestions and add an answer if I get something valuable.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternative bubble pop effect I created.

http://jsfiddle.net/EkZBg

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="bubble"></div>
  <div id="dummy_debris" class="debris" />
</div>

<script>

$(function(){
  // Document is ready
  $("#bubble").on("click", function(e) {
    pop(e.pageX, e.pageY, 13);
  });
});

function r2d(x) {
    return x / (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  function d2r(x) {
    return x * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  // Specify particle_count as 10 + Math.random()*10 to make things interesting!
  function pop(start_x, start_y, particle_count) {
    arr = [];
    angle = 0;
    particles = [];
    offset_x = $("#dummy_debris").width() / 2;
    offset_y = $("#dummy_debris").height() / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < particle_count; i++) {
      rad = d2r(angle);
      x = Math.cos(rad)*(80+Math.random()*20);
      y = Math.sin(rad)*(80+Math.random()*20);
      arr.push([start_x + x, start_y + y]);
      // You could use an IMG tag here instead to make the particles sprites
      z = $('<div class="debris" />');
      z.css({
        "left": start_x - offset_x,
        "top": start_y - offset_x
      }).appendTo($("#content"));
      particles.push(z);
      angle += 360/particle_count;
    }

    $.each(particles, function(i, v){
      $(v).show();
      $(v).animate({
        top: arr[i][1], 
        left: arr[i][0],
        width: 4, 
        height: 4, 
        opacity: 0
      }, 600, function(){
        $(v).remove()
      });
    });
  }
</script>

<style>
/* Add browser prefixes as-needed. See CSS3please.com */
.debris {
 display: none;   
 position: absolute;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 background-color: #ff00ff;
 opacity: 1.0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 8px;
}

#bubble {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  left:150px;
  top:150px;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 9;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to perform very well when using a lot of fragments (>100), also the starting element should be removed as the explosion goes

Comment: You did not specify that you needed "more than 100" fragments. Javascript is not a high-performance graphics engine. You can boost performance by using CSS3 animations or transitions which make use of hardware acceleration. Hiding the original element is pretty trivial. You seemed to grasp the basics so I left that up to you. Add this to the click handler: $(this).hide();

Comment: I can't just hide() the element, the result would not be good. Also, 100+ fragments is what seems to be needed for your script to actually have a decent effect

Comment: This is a really nice effect that you've created. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a CSS only click effect I used to animate my copy to clipboard button:

```css
#clickbox{
  display:none;
}
label {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1);
}

#clickbox:checked + label::before{
  transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.75);
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: pre;
   content: '\A\A Copied';
  border: 6px solid hsl(236, 32%, 26%);
}
#clickbox:checked + label i{
  color:#9A9A9A;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <body style="margin:20px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="clickbox"/>
    <label for="clickbox" class="copy-click"><i id="container-id-copy" class="fa fa-clipboard"></i></label>
  </body>
</html>
```